# jQuery document.location not working IE(typical)

Tags: jquery

I hate hate IE! Now that I've ranted, I could really do with some help. I have this site here. http://pearsonlyle.uwpistol.net/galleries/susie-theodorou/editorial/ only susie works, and I wrote some javascript that adds the overlay when the nav is clicked, I have added a function to fadeout the navoverlay and redirect the page to the selected link but in IE8 my page content (Galleria) doesn't display. However in IE7 my page content (galleria) displays minus all the thumbnails but one.

I have taken out the code (resize.js and menus.js) and still can't find the root of the problem, I know it's a long shot to get help on these forums especially with something so complicated. I'm not even sure I can explain my code but I really need help so i'll give it a go.

menus.js

```
function initMenuPhotographers() {

 $('#navsub_533013_583913 ul').hide();
 $('#navsub_533013_583913 li a').click(
  function() {
   var checkElement = $(this).next();
 if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
   return false;
     }
 if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
  $('#navsub_533013_583913 ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
  checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  return false;
        }
    });
 }
function initMenuStylists() {

     $('#navsub_533015_584326 ul').hide();
  $('#navsub_533015_584326 li a').click(
        function() {
   var checkElement = $(this).next();
   if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
   return false;
   }
   if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
   $('#navsub_533015_584326 ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
   checkElement.slideDown('normal');
   return false;
  }
             });
   }  

function addNavLightbox(){
 $("< div id='nav-overlay'>< /div>")
  .css('top', $(document).scrollTop())
  .css('opacity', '0')
  .animate({'opacity':'0.8'}, 'slow')
  .appendTo('body');
 }

function removeNavLightbox(){
  $('#nav-overlay')
  .fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $(this).remove();
  });
  }

function redirectPage() {
 window.location.href = linkLocation;
 } 


   $(document).ready(function() {


  $("#navsub_533015_584326 li ul li a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
   $('#nav-overlay').fadeOut(30, redirectPage);
  });


    initMenuPhotographers();
    initMenuStylists();

     $('#navsub_533013_583913').hide();
      $('#navsub_533015_584326').hide();

    $('#photographers').click(
   function(){
    $('#navsub_533013_583913').slideToggle();
   });


  $('#photographers').toggle(addNavLightbox, removeNavLightbox);


 $('#stylists').click(
       function(){
           $('#navsub_533015_584326').slideToggle();

  });


  $('#stylists').toggle(addNavLightbox, removeNavLightbox);
  });
```

I know there's a lot of code, there's an accordion for the menus, and the overlay also for the menu's.

I also have a galleria function in another script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(function () {
     $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "img/PhotoGallery.xml", 
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml) {
    $(xml).find('img').each(function() {
    var location = 'img/'; 
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('< img src="'+location+''+url+'" alt="'+alt+'"/>').appendTo('#galleria');

   });

   // Load theme
   Galleria.loadTheme('/js/src/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js');



   $('#galleria').galleria({
    image_crop: false, // crop all images to fit
    thumb_crop: true, // crop all thumbnails to fit
    transition: 'fade', // crossfade photos
    transition_speed: 20, // slow down the crossfade
     extend: function() {

      this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {

                                        $('.counter').html(this.$('counter').html());
      })

      var gallery = this;
      var playing = false;
                                                                 $('#playpause').bind('click', function() {
       if (! playing) {
                                                       gallery.play();
                                                       $(this).text('Pause Slideshow');
       } else {
                                                       gallery.pause();
                $(this).text('Play Slideshow');
       }
       playing = !playing;
       });
         //get thumbnail width
     var thumbnailWidth = $('.galleria-thumbnails').width();
     $('.galleria-thumbnails').css({"width" : thumbnailWidth, "margin-left" : "auto", "margin-right" : "auto"})
     $('.galleria-stage').css('z-index', '500');
     }
  });



       }

      });

     })


 });
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction or even tell me how to debug in IE, also this galleria code works in IE on a lot of other projects so it shoudln't (She says) be that...

I'm not looking for the answer, just hoping someone has a few ideas.

Thanks so much for taking the time to read this, I really appreciate it.
Tara

Comment: Why can't I post all my code at once?

Comment: Select your code and click on the {} button in the editor. I feel your pain about IE.

Comment: Or just indent your code blocks with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `debug:true` option to the galleria widget.  That should help you to figure out what's going wrong;

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    debug: true,
    image_crop: false, // crop all images to fit
    thumb_crop: true, // crop all thumbnails to fit
    transition: 'fade', // crossfade photos
    transition_speed: 20, // slow down the crossfade
    extend: function() {
        this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {
            $('.counter').html(this.$('counter').html());
        })

        var gallery = this;
        var playing = false;

        $('#playpause').bind('click', function() {
            if (! playing) {
                gallery.play();
                $(this).text('Pause Slideshow');
            } else {
                gallery.pause();
                $(this).text('Play Slideshow');
            }
            playing = !playing;
        });

        //get thumbnail width
        var thumbnailWidth = $('.galleria-thumbnails').width();
        $('.galleria-thumbnails').css({
            "width" : thumbnailWidth, 
            "margin-left" : "auto", 
            "margin-right" : "auto"});
        $('.galleria-stage').css('z-index', '500');
    }
});
```